# Preventdefault and submitting form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, uploadify, preventdefault

I have problem with submit fire in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#zestaw-edytuj-form').submit(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#ip_dilmarbundle_zestawytype_path').uploadify('upload');
                    });

                    $('#ip_dilmarbundle_zestawytype_path').uploadify({
                        'swf'      : '{{ asset("js/uploadify/uploadify.swf") }}',
                        'uploader' : '{{ path('upload-image') }}',
                        'folder'   : '{{ asset("images") }}',
                        'auto'     : false,
                        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file,data,response) {
                            $('#ip_dilmarbundle_zestawytype_zdjecie').attr('value',file.name);

                        },
                        'onUploadComplete' : function(file) {
                            $('#zestaw-edytuj-form').submit();
                        },
                        'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {

                        },
                    });
                });
```

First, after submit button click i need to preventdefault and upload image. When upload is complete (onUploadComplete) i need to normally submit the form. But when image uploads, submit doesn't fire. What can I do with that?

Comment: a trailing `,` here at the end of `'onUploadError : func(){},'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**EDITED**: fixed this too: a trailing , here at the end of 'onUploadError : func(){},'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ready = false;

$('#zestaw-edytuj-form').submit(function(e) {
    if(!ready){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#ip_dilmarbundle_zestawytype_path').uploadify('upload');
    }
});

$('#ip_dilmarbundle_zestawytype_path').uploadify({
    'swf'      : '{{ asset("js/uploadify/uploadify.swf") }}',
    'uploader' : '{{ path('upload-image') }}',
    'folder'   : '{{ asset("images") }}',
    'auto'     : false,
    'onUploadSuccess' : function(file,data,response) {
        $('#ip_dilmarbundle_zestawytype_zdjecie').attr('value',file.name);

    },
    'onUploadComplete' : function(file) {
        ready = true;
        $('#zestaw-edytuj-form').submit();
    },
    'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a formula for a submit loop here if it were to work. A couple of suggestions. You could separate your form into two forms (separate form tags) with one for the file upload and one for the input data. When the file upload finishes then submit the data form. Probably the best way however is that with uploadify you can send other additional data as a parameter so your same script handling the file upload could also process the incoming data. You can get the form params like`var myform = $(this).serializeArray()` and I believe the parameter is `formData` so you would set it `'formData':myform` in the uploadify() config parameters. (Reference: The Uploadify site is down right now http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/.